# Inequalities in eigenvalues of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

Suppose $Q$ is an $n\times n$ positive (componentwise) matrix. I want to put the condition that the eigenvalues of $Q$ are greater than a positive constant, say $a$. I am aware that we can write this as an LMI: $Q\succeq aI$ ($I$ is the identity matrix). My doubt is, can we write that $\frac{Q+Q^T}{2}\succeq aI$ as its sufficient condition? (we are NOT assuming that $Q$ is symmetric) I tried it out for $2\times 2$ and $3\times 3$ matrices in MATLAB, but I can neither find a proof nor a counter-example. But it seems to be true as we are assuming the matrix to be positive. Any help in terms of hint or reference will be appreciated. Thank you. 
EDIT: Long question short, does this implication hold true under the above-given conditions: $\frac{Q+Q^T}{2}\succeq aI \Rightarrow$ Absolute eigenvalues of $Q$ are greater than or equal to $a$.

Comment: What if the eigenvalues of $Q$ are complex-valued?

Comment: If they are complex-valued, we consider their modulus. I am very sorry, I should have specified this. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

The product of all the eigenvalues $\omega_n$ of a $n×n$ matrix is its determinants $\Delta$, we are looking for the condition that puts the eigenvalues greater than a positive constant $\alpha$
$$ \omega_1 \cdot \omega_2 \cdot \omega_3 \dots \dots \omega_n  = \Delta$$
If the determinant $\Delta$ is negative, at least one of the eigenvalue $\omega$ must also be negative... So negative determinants are an exception here

Lets us consider a $2×2$ matrix with random elements
$$ Q = 
\begin{pmatrix}
q_1&q_2\\
q_3&q_4\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
Here the determinant $\Delta = q_1q_4-q_2q_3$, the expressiond $ q_1+q_4$ is its trace and it's eigenvalues $\omega$ are roots of the equation
$$\omega^2-(q_1+q_4)\omega+q_1q_4-q_2q_3 = 0$$
If the eigenvalues are all positive, then both the trace and determinants must be positive too, and if the eigenvalues was greater than a positive constant $\alpha$, so also
$$ \alpha^2-(q_1+q_4)\alpha+q_1q_4-q_2q_3 \geq 0$$
So we would need more information, if we were considering higher order matrix

Basically it all depends on the equation of the eigenvalue of the $n×n$ matrix
$$\omega^n-(\dots)\omega^{n-1}+(\dots)\omega^{n-2}-(\dots)\omega^{n-3}+\dots \dots +\Delta = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

It can be shown that if $\frac{Q+Q^T}{2}- aI$ is positive semi-definite, then so is $Q-aI$.

$$
{\frac{Q+Q^T}{2}\succeq aI \iff
\\
\frac{Q+Q^T}{2}- aI\succeq0\iff
\\
v^T\frac{Q+Q^T}{2}v- av^TIv\ge0\iff
\\
\frac{v^TQv+v^TQ^Tv}{2}- av^TIv\ge0\iff
\\
v^TQv-av^TIv\ge0\iff
\\
v^T(Q-aI)v\ge0\iff
\\
Q-aI\succeq0\iff
\\Q\succeq aI
}
$$
where we have used $v^TQ^Tv=v^TQv$.